# Weird behaviour of stringstream?

Tags: c++11, stringstream

I am not able to understand why after reaching the last word it doesn't output blank or null character or garbage value or anything else . Why >> doesn't has any impact whatsoever after finishing the string .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stringstream ss("I am going to goa for");  // Used for breaking words
    string word; // To store individual words
    while (ss >> word)
        cout<<word<<"\n";
    ss >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
    ss >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
    ss >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
I
am
going
to
goa
for
for
for
for
```

Comment: Your stream has an error flag set (that's why the while loop terminated), yet you still keep reading from it.

Answer (score 1):

When `>>` reaches the end of the string, the failbit is set and it stops reading further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    stringstream ss("I am going to goa for");  // Used for breaking words
    string word; // To store individual words
    while (ss >> word)
        cout<<word<<"\n";

    word = "END";
    ss >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
    ss >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
    ss >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
}
```

You are seeing the `for` because that is what stored in it. Change it to something else you will find that it doesn't read from the `stringstream` till `failbit` is cleared.

The output is:

```
I
am
going
to
goa
for
END
END
END
```

Refer [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Before every `cout << word << endl;` line you should add `if(!ss.fail())` to check no error has occurred in the stringstream following the read attempt.